# How to change python module path

Tags: python, python-2.7

I install a python2.7.6 locally, and there is another 2.7.6 installed on cluster publicly.

Then I use my local python to install a pip but when I 'pip list', it returns:

> $ pip list Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/zengh/.local/bin/pip", line 7, in 
>       from pip import main   File "/home/zengh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/**init**.py", line
>   13, in 
>       from pip.utils import get_installed_distributions, get_prog   File "/home/zengh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/**init**.py",
>   line 5, in 
>       import locale   File "/home/software/rhel6/python/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 18,
>   in 
>       import operator ImportError: /home/software/rhel6/python/2.7.6/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.so:
>   undefined symbol: _PyUnicodeUCS2_AsDefaultEncodedString

Obviously it calls the locale.py on the cluster while my PYTHONPATH only contains my local python's path. How can I make it call the

/.local/python2.7.6/lib/python2.7/locale.py?

Thanks

Comment: How did your get your local python installed?

Comment: The solution might also be: Do not install a second Python2.7. What for did you install a second Python2.7? Maybe there is an other solution to your original problem.

Comment: It is because 'undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_Decode' appeared when I run the python from original python on the cluster. So I install it as `/configure --prefix=/home/username/.local/python2.7.6 --enable-shared -enable-unicode=ucs4
$make;make install `

Answer (score 1):

Depends on whether you want to set it from within a script or from os.

**From script:**

```
    import sys
    sys.path.append('additional dir')
```

**From os:**

```
    export PYTHONPATH=somewhere
```

Comment: Hi mstuebner, this dosen't work to me. I've already use [from os] to set PYTHONPATH includes local python path and excludes public python path. But pip/utils/_init_.py will still call the locale.py on the cluster. Thanks